# Set hikari pool size for custom DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I want to change Hikari pool size for my custom DataSource, I use Spring boot 2+ version.

I can set dataSource url,dataSource password etc.
I wrote values to application.properties file.After that I read these values with environment.getproperty and set dataSource but I donot know same process for pool size:(

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you custom your dataSource by set your DataSource bean. then you can create custom hikariconfig as follow, remember to replace hard code values below with values in your environment.getproperty:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://yourhostname:port/dbname");
        config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        config.setUsername("dbUsername");
        config.setPassword("dbPassword");
        config.setMinimumIdle(10);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        config.setConnectionTimeout(1500);
        //you can set more config here

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hikari [prefix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) is `spring.datasource.hikari.`

You can set maximum pool size as 10:

```
 spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
```

> spring.datasource.hikari.*= # Hikari specific settings

It will automatically set your pool size

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I cannot set these line because I use custom dataSource.Actually I get pool initialization error and too many connections error so I want to change it

Comment: After hikari-6 is running, I get above errors for hikari 7-8-9-10

Comment: @sneijder10 if it's set in code you can `dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10)` if not working please provide code or more details on your settings